# BeautifulSoup doesn't recognize subclasses after <main class=

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I needed to parse a news site and the title and link to the news were in <main class='single-module__Main-sc-1qdjg1k-0 iMZnZU' . I tried to query subclasses but couldn't. soup.prettyfi() produced such a complete markup

```
    <div class="single-module__Inner-sc-1qdjg1k-1 mIFFS">
      <header class="sticky-header">
       <div data-fusion-collection="features" data-fusion-message="Could not render component [features:global/main-navigation]" data-fusion-type="global/main-navigation" id="f0fj2XGPHYgA9Rb" style="display:none">
       </div>
      </header>
      <main class="single-module__Main-sc-1qdjg1k-0 iMZnZU">
       <div data-fusion-collection="features" data-fusion-message="Could not render component [features:global/search-page]" data-fusion-type="global/search-page" id="f0f1nZqKTkTE1lq" style="display:none">
       </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
       <div data-fusion-collection="features" data-fusion-message="Could not render component [features:global/footer]" data-fusion-type="global/footer" id="f0fUuwTNo76j9AD" style="display:none">
       </div>
      </footer>
```

I tried to see the subclasses  but get the same result

```
q = soup.find('div', class_='layout-container').find('div','single-module__Inner-sc-1qdjg1k-1mIFFS')
print(q.find('main','single-module__Main-sc-1qdjg1k-0 iMZnZU')
```

Comment: Remember that `find` only returns the FIRST matching element.  Could there be more than one?

Comment: @TimRoberts  when trying to use soup.find_all('div') or soup.find('div', class_='layout-container').find_all('div') all the same most of the classes give "Could not render component [features:global /search-page]"

Comment: You're missing `class_=` in the second call to `find()`

Comment: But that's the right answer, isn't it?  The contents of that `<main>` element is `<div>` that contains that text.  What are you expecting?  It's likely that the actual text of the page is filled in dynamically, using Javascript.  It won't be in the HTML.

Comment: @TimRoberts Most likely correct, I specified class_ and looked at the subclasses several times but the output did not change. I should use another parsing framework instead of
bs4?

Comment: In addition to Barmar's comment, in the first line of your code there is a space missing. `1mIFFS` should be `1 mIFFS`.

Comment: try: `q = soup.select_one('.single-module__Inner-sc-1qdjg1k-1.mIFFS')
print(q.select_one('.single-module__Main-sc-1qdjg1k-0.iMZnZU'))`

Comment: @CompDet <main class="single-module__Main-sc-1qdjg1k-0 iMZnZU"><div data-fusion-collection="features" data-fusion-message="Could not render component [features:global/search-page]" as said Tim Roberts this is most likely due to dynamic page filled

Comment: I see. I tested it just with the html code provided by you. Can you link the URL? @ИНДУСГеймдев

Comment: https://www.coindesk.com/search?s=btc

Comment: There's no issue with bs4s parsing. It's that you don't have any content yet. Interact with the dom and then save it as text before parsing with bs4. I'd use bs4s in conjunction with other tools.

Comment: You cannot use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` for this.  You will have to use a genuine browser, meaning `requests-html` or `Selenium`, and then use those APIs to interact with the dynamic DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of getting those news -- they are being hydrated into page by a separate XHR call, so you can scrape that API endpoint directly:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://api.queryly.com/json.aspx?queryly_key=d0ab87fd70264c0a&query=btc&batchsize=10&showfaceted=true&maxfacetitems=75&extendeddatafields=basic,creator,creator_slug,subheadlines,primary_section,report_url,section_path,sections_paths,subtype,type,imageresizer,section,sponsored_label,sponsored,promo_image,pubDate&timezoneoffset=-60'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['items'])
display(df[['section', 'subtype', 'title', 'pubdate', 'link', 'section_path', 'image']])
```

Result in terminal:

```
section     subtype     title   pubdate     link    section_path    image
0   Markets     story_news  First Mover Asia: Bitcoin Whales Are Increasin...   Jul 07, 2023    /markets/2023/07/07/first-mover-asia-bitcoin-w...   /markets    https://cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublish...
1   Markets     story_news  Bitcoin Drops Below $30K as Altcoins Tumble; B...   Jun 28, 2023    /markets/2023/06/28/bitcoin-drops-below-30k-as...   /markets    https://cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublish...
2   Policy  story_news  Bankrupt Celsius Can Convert Altcoins to BTC, ...   Jun 30, 2023    /policy/2023/06/30/bankrupt-celsius-can-conver...   /policy     
3   Finance|Markets     story_news  Celsius to Potentially Sell More Than $170M in...   Jun 30, 2023    /business/2023/06/30/celsius-to-potentially-se...   /business   https://cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublish...
4   Markets     story_news  Bitcoin Tumbles on Report of SEC Saying Spot B...   Jun 30, 2023    /markets/2023/06/30/bitcoin-tumbles-on-report-...   /markets    
5   Markets     story_news  First Mover Asia: Bitcoin Crosses $31K After S...   Jul 04, 2023    /markets/2023/07/04/first-mover-asia-bitcoin-c...   /markets    https://cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublish...
6   Mercados|Coindesk-ES    story_news  El gran repunte de bitcoin impulsado por los E...   Jun 22, 2023    /es/markets/2023/06/22/el-gran-repunte-de-bitc...   /es/markets     
7   Markets     story_news  Bitcoin’s Ferocious ETF-Fueled Rally Puts Ethe...   Jun 22, 2023    /markets/2023/06/22/bitcoins-ferocious-etf-fue...   /markets    
8   Finance     story_news  CME Group Announces Plans to Launch ETH to BTC...   Jun 29, 2023    /business/2023/06/29/cme-group-announces-plans...   /business   
9   Markets     story_news  First Mover Asia: Bitcoin Holds Firm Above $30...   Jun 22, 2023    /markets/2023/06/22/first-mover-asia-bitcoin-h...   /markets
```